# What is the correct syntax for passing a hidden form field into a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, xml

Here is the code for my JavaScript function:

```
function PopUpScreen(txt) {
     alert(txt);
 }
```

And here is the code used to call the JavaScript function:

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CertID") & "," &  Eval("ReportID") & "," & Eval("PUCOID") %> ' OnClientClick='javascript:PopUpScreen(" + Container.DataItem("ReportToolTipText") + ");' OnCommand="CertLink_Clicked"><%# Container.DataItem("CertID")%></asp:LinkButton>
```

This code works just fine when I attempt to pass a simple numerical value into the PopUpScreen function, bringing up an alert window that displays the number I passed into the function.  However, when I attempt to pass in the text value Container.DataItem("ReportToolTipText"), nothing happens.  I have spent over a day working on this, tweaking the syntax again and again and again until I no longer received any error messages.  I am beyond the end of my rope.  Any assistance anyone can provide me would mean the world to me.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: What is `Container.DataItem("ReportToolTipText")`?  Is that an ASP object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the reference to `Container.DataItem` has to be contained within the tags `<%#` and `%>` to work properly.  Look at the VIEW SOURCE for the rendered page and find the markup for `LinkButton1` -- I think you will discover that the `Container.DataItem` reference was not 'executed' and remains unchanged in the markup.

Comment: I don't know asp but I guess there is problems with the `OnClientClick='javascript:PopUpScreen(" + Container.DataItem("ReportToolTipText") + ");'` quotation

Comment: I tried enclosing the Container.DataItem("ReportToolTipText") in the <%# and #> tags, and when I did, the exact same thing happened.  No pop-up window appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it in VB.Net for you but you will have to convert it to C#.  Change the variable txt string to your Container.DataItem

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim txt As String = "Hello"

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType(), "PopUpScreen", 
  alert('" & txt & "');", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: There should be a quote " before alert but it wouldn't allow me to put it in

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the problems with the WebForms framework. Your ASP and C# code are so far apart from what happens in the browser it becomes hard to do something like this. You can do this all in JavaScript:

```
<asp:LinkButton ... OnClientClick='PopUpScreen(this.value);' ... ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Two things:

1. The value of `OnClientClick` is just plain JavaScript, so `this` inside the `OnClientClick` attribute references the `<input type="hidden">` tag in the browser, and is executed in the browser.
2. Remove `javascript:` from the `OnClientClick` attribute value. This becomes and `onclick` attribute in HTML, and the browser already knows the value of this attribute is JavaScript. The `javascript:` prefix is only required if you plan on executing JavaScript from the `href` of a link:

   Correct:

   ```
   <a href="javascript:alert('Hi!')">Say Hi</a>
   ```

   Incorrect:

   ```
   <a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('Hi!')">Say Hi</a>
   ```

   Correct:

   ```
   <a href="#" onclick="alert('Hi!')">Say Hi</a>
   ```